# sendmailR adding CC address

Tags: r, sendmailr

I am using sendmailR to automatically send out emails. I want to cc a copy to one address in order to keep as a record. The code I've used is:

```
>from <- "<abc@sample.com.cn>"

>to <- 'def@sample.com.cn'

>header<-list(Cc=c("<hij@sample.com.cn>"))

>subject <- "test1"

>body <- 'test1';

>mailControl=list(smtpServer="mail.sample.com.cn")

>sendmail(from=from,to=to,subject=subject,msg=body,headers=header,control=mailControl)
```

The cc part never worked, and I could not figure out why. I've referred to this post: [Is it possible to cc recipients using sendmail in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539497/is-it-possible-to-cc-recipients-using-sendmail-in-r), but it seems everything should be correct.

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: you are not supplying any `cc` addresses in your `header`

Comment: why? can you show me an example?

Comment: you need to remove the brackets from the e-mail addresses.

Comment: I change the header to header<-list(Cc=c("hij@sample.com.cn")), but it still doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

"cc" and "bcc" are arguments to sendmailR::sendmail as of version 1.2-1, which is available on CRAN: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sendmailR/index.html